# Rouche's Theorem application and find mulitplicity

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine the number of zeros, with multiplicity, of the polynomial $f(z) =
1+4z^3 +z^{10} +2z^{12}$ inside the annulus $\{z \in \mathbb{C}:1<|z|<2\}$

First we consider the unit disk $|z|<1$.

Let $g(z)=-z^{10}$

Then $|f(z)+g(z)|= |1+4z^3+2z^{12}|= 7 < 8 = |f(z)|$

So by Rouche's theorem, $f $ and $g$ have the same number of zeros. Since $g$ has 10, $f$ has 10.

Now consider the disk $|z|<2$.

Let $g(z)=-2z^{12}$.

Then $|f(z)+g(z)|= |1+2^4+2^{10}| < 2^{13}$.

So So by Rouche's theorem, $f $ and $g$ have the same number of zeros. Since $g$ has 12, $f$ has 12.

Thus, in $\{z \in \mathbb{C}:1<|z|<2\}$, we get 2 zeros.

Now for the multiplicity, usually we want to check the derivative.

So we have $f(z) = 1+4z^3 +z^{10} +2z^{12}$  and $f'(z)= 12z^2+10z^9+24z^{11}$. But from here, I'm not sure how to find the zeros.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $|f(z)| = 8$ $(|z|=1)$ is wrong. In fact $f(-1)=0$.

Comment: For $|z|=1$ the term $4z^3$ is dominating. So you should take $g(z)=4z^3.$ For $f'$ the term $24z^{11}$ is dominating for $|z|=2$ and for $|z|=1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc How to show that $4z^3$ is dominating? Note that the inequality of Rouche's theorem on the boundary is strict. Moreover, Rouche's theorem includes the multiplicity of the roots and therefore, I think that there's no need to check $f'(z)$.

Comment: @on1921379 My bad. I have missed one term. Concerning multiplicity you cannot rely on Rouche theorem without studying $f'.$ For example $f(z)= 2z^n-1$ has simple roots but $2z^n$ doesn't, in the open unit ball.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc You are right, Thanks.

Comment: Wait, so don't know if $4z^3$ is dominating, because it won't be not a strict inequality. But why can't we choose $f(z)$ to be the dominating term?

Comment: What $f(z)$ ? As was observed in the first comment $f(-1)=0.$ The Rouche theorem is applied as follows if $|h(z)|<|g(z)|$ on the boundary of a region then the functions $f(z)=g(z)+h(z)$ and $g(z)$ have the same number of zeros in the interior. Usually you are given $f$ and you look for $g$ possibly  simpler for determining the number of roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was proved by the asker the function $f(z)=1+4z^3+z^{10}+2z^{12}$ has $12$ roots in the open unit ball $|z|<2$ as the term $2z^{12}$ is dominating on the circle $|z|=2.$

For $0<\delta<1$ consider the circle $|z|=1-\delta.$ When $\delta\to 0^+$ we get
$$ 4|z|^3= 4-12\delta+o(\delta^2)$$ $$1+|z|^{10}+2|z|^{12}= 1+(1-10\delta)+2(1-12\delta)+o(\delta^2)=4-34\delta+o(\delta^2) $$ Therefore for $\delta>0$ small enough the term $4z^3$ is dominating on the circle $|z|=1-\delta.$ Hence the function $f(z)$ has $3$ roots in the open ball $|z|<1-\delta$ for  every $\delta>0$ small enough. Hence $f(z)$ has $3$ roots in $|z|<1.$

It remains to determine the number of roots on the circle $|z|=1.$ Assume $z_0$ satisfies $f(z_0)=0$ and $|z_0|=1.$ Then
$$-4z_0^3=1+z_0^{10}+2z_0^{12}$$ hence
$$4=|1+z_0^{10}+2z_0^{12}|$$ The equality implies $z_0^{10}=z_0^{12}=1,$ i.e. $z_0=\pm 1.$ We have $f(-1)=0$ and $f(1)\neq 0.$

Summarizing the function $f(z)$ has $12-3-1=8$ roots in the region $1<|z|<2.$

Concerning multiplicity, for every root $z_0$ with multiplicity greater than $1,$ there holds $f'(z_0)=0.$
We have
$$f'(z)= 12z^2+10z^9+24z^{11} $$ The term $24z^{11}$ is dominating on the circle $|z|=1$ as well as Therefore  all $11$ roots of  $f'(z)$ are located in the open ball $|z|<1.$ Thus all the roots in the region $1\le |z|<2$ are single.

**Remark**
It turns out that also $3$ roots of $f(z)$ located in $|z|<1$ are single as well. It follows from the fact that (according to Wolphram Alpha GCD algorithm or [this](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/polynomial-gcd-calculator/gcd%202z%5E%7B12%7D%2Bz%5E%7B10%7D%2B4z%5E%7B3%7D%2B1%2C%2012z%5E%7B9%7D%2B5z%5E%7B7%7D%2B6?or=input)) the polynomials $f(z)$ and $f'(z)$ are relatively prime, i.e. they do not have a common divisor. That means they do not have a common root.

Comment: Very nice explanation.+1